# Firebase Task is not yet complete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, kotlin, google-signin

I am getting following exception randomly after signing out of Firebase using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` and signing in again

I am trying to get the token from FirebaseUser after the user is successfully authenticated
`signUpRequest.firebaseToken = user.getIdToken(true).result?.token`

user is the FirebaseUser received after authentication

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: agrahyah.keen, PID: 12082
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete 
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbp.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.zzbic(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.getResult(Unknown Source)
       at com.xxxActivity.makeSignUpRequest(xxxActivity.kt:129)
       at com.xxxActivity.access$makeSignUpRequest(xxxActivity.kt:36)
       at com.xxxActivity$signInAnonymously$1.onComplete(xxxActivity.kt:94)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I am using Firebase android sdk version `11.2.2`. This error never occured on previous versions of the Firebase SDK

Comment: Do you have any other processes that is still running while you're trying to signOut() the user ? It seems like it might be the problem here

Comment: Could you show your code that listens to the Task?  Are you absolutely certain that this didn't happen in 11.2.0?

Answer (score 16):

Try to receive result asynchronously (through `.addOnSuccessListener{...}`) or check flag `isSuccessful` from `Task`.

Comment: I am calling signUpRequest method from addOnCompleteListener with condition if (task.isSuccessful) { }

Comment: @Rinav Try to use addOnSuccessListener(). Cause it call when you receive result, otherwise addOnCompleteListener call when task complete, but not completed

Comment: @Eduard How do I keep my application *wait* till I receive successful result,Currently I am using FusedLocationProviderClient

Comment: What if I need to get result on offline? or listen that data is added offline?

Comment: for me, onCompleteListener shows the task as complete, and I still get task is not complete. I even have if(task.()isComplete && task.isSuccessful() ) as checks and it still persists. I also noticed onSuccess is called before onComplete.

Answer (score 13):

I tried the answers above but implementing `OnSuccessListener` or `OnCompleteListener` doesn't give my calling thread a way to wait until the task is complete. `task.getResult` is supposed to wait, but for some reason, it was sporadially exiting with the exception above.

Finally, the code below seems to have fixed it:

```
tokenTask = firebaseUser.getIdToken(false);
Tasks.await(tokenTask);
@NotNull GetTokenResult tokenResult = Objects.requireNonNull(tokenTask.getResult());
```

In short, I am explicitly waiting for the task to complete and then calling `task.getResult`. Only calling `Tasks.await(tokenTask)` without calling `task.getResult` does not seem to work either, as `Tasks.await(tokenTask)` somehow seems to exit before the task is complete. I am not sure why calling both is working.

By the way, putting a breakpoint in the debugger causes the code to work because it gives the task time to complete, so this is a bit hard to debug.

Comment: I have run into the same problem with FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getId().getResult(); , i tried your solution but got an exception that the Tasks.await should not be called from the main thread...
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this using the [Kotlin+Coroutine extensions for Google Play Services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services):

```
// gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.6'
}
```

```kotlin
// code
val token = user.getIdToken(true).await().token
```

Comment: Usually I wouldn't download a library just to solve a simple problem but the lib is SO lightweight that I don't see why not. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SnapShotListener, just like recomended on [Firebase's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=pt&authuser=0):

```html
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document("id");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                         @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
           if (e != null) {
               Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
               return;
           }
           if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {

               // HERE IS WHERE I GET THE MAP TO USE WHEREVER I WANT                    
               Map ds;
               ds = snapshot.getData();

               // TOAST CONFIRMS WHAT EVENT HAPPENED AND IT'S CONTENT
               Toast.makeText(ItemsListActivity.this, ds.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Log.d(TAG, "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
          } else {
               Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
          }
     }});
```

Hope I've helped.